# Exposing QML Components to each other in Qt Creator

Tags: python, qml, qtquick2, pyside2

I'm developing a dashboard application using Qt-Quick with PySide2 and am having trouble exposing my QML components in Qt Creator's design mode.

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
myapp/
├── mycomponents
│   ├── component1.qml
│   └── component2.qml
│   └── etc..
├── pages
│   ├── page1.qml
│   └── page2.qml
└── app.qml
```

I can use all components from `myapp/mycomponents` by importing the appropriate .qml files or it's parent directory using relative paths:

```
// inside page1.qml

import "../mycomponents"

Item {
    id:page1

    MyComponent1 {
        // some code
    }

}
```

The problem is that I'm unable to see the components from `myapp/components` in the **My QML Components** tab when I open up a `page.qml` (or any other .qml file in a sibling directory) file in **Qt Creator --> Design**.

All components available to app.qml

[image]

But not in page1.qml

[image]

***How can I expose*** `myapp/components` ***to .qml files located in sibling directories without changing the folder structure of my project?***

**Edit 1:**
I've already read [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-modules-with-plugins.html) regarding `designer.metainfo` but they all seem to refer to plugin applications which mine isn't. So I have a hard time making these work for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

The designer only shows components from the current directories or from used imports(which can be a c++ plugin, but also qmldir with some qml components instead).
So you have to create an import and add that somehow to the loaded project - not sure what pyside uses, but maybe it is a good idea to create a myapp.qmlproject file for all the qml stuff and inside that you need:

```
importPaths: [ "." ]
```

then inside the mycomponents directory, you need a qmldir file

```
Component1 1.0 Component1.qml
```

also, you need the designer directory with the file mycomponents.metainfo

```
MetaInfo {
    Type {
        name: "Component1"

        ItemLibraryEntry {
            name: "a Test Component1"
            category: "mycomponents"
            version: "1.0"
            requiredImport: "mycomponents"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, you have to close and reopen the project to see the result.

I prepared a small example [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=19297531601404361286)