# What is the easiest way to make custom components from different directories show up in QML-Designer?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I recently started a new QtQuick-project (QtQuick2 with Qt 5.12.2).
In this project, I am trying to make custom components from two different directories available on various pages in the form editor of the designer (per drag and drop from the toolbox like the qt default components).
If I import the folders containing my custom elements, I can use them in the text editor, but they do not show up in the form editor.
Also if I create a new form in one of the component-folders, I can see my custom components like this:

[image]

So how can I get the same result for components in one or multiple different folders?

I already tried adding the folders to QML_IMPORT_PATH and QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH in my .pro, but with no result.
The components are in this folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at my answer [Exposing QML Components to each other in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610681/exposing-qml-components-to-each-other-in-qt-creator/53055216#53055216)

also read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html